# Raspbian: Reading USB port intermittently works

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, python3

I have a Raspberry Pi running Linux - Raspbian.

The problem is that I'm seeing odd behavior when I try to read the USB port. It gives intermittent results.

Last night it worked, this morning it doesn't - same exact code.

`dmesg | grep tty` returns-

```
[    0.000301] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.812585] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 81, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.814150] 3f215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 53, base_baud = 31250000) is a 16550
[    4.867127] cdc_acm 1-1.5:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

My device is at port  `ttyACM0`.

I can confirm the port is open when I checked with `ser.isOpen()`.

When I then open a Python3 terminal, I run the following:

```
import serial
port = "ttyACM0"
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/%s" % port, 9600, timeout=0.5)
while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    print(line)
    print(line.decode())
```

Last night it returned what I was writing to the port. 
[image]

This morning all it returns:

```
b''

b''

b''
```

I have changed the USB cable, and checked the device that is writing to the port is writing data.

My only guess is that it is something within Linux/Raspbian, but I am not sure.

Any ideas on how to debug this further?